# VS2017 C++ Memory continuely increasing when a opengl process is running until an interuption ocurred

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw

The problem is: when I want to draw a simple graph, the window will occur an interruption after running for a while.

**The interruption info is :**

*igc32.pdb was't loaded.*

Then I notice that the memory of the process is increasing continuely until the interruption occured.

**output of the command line shows :**

*glError:1285*

*LLVM ERROR:out of memory.*

Some arrays of dynamic memory allocating is used in functions but I delete them at the end of the definition of the functions. So I don't really know whether the problem is because if the codes or not. The details are all showed below, many thx to anyone helps me! Just dont mind of the Chinese(I'm a Chinese learner).

Memory used:

[image]

The output is below:

[image]

[image]

The code is showed below:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Utils.h"
using namespace std;

#define numVAOs 1
#define numVBOs 1
#define PI 3.1415926535
#define CR PI/5
//全局变量
GLuint renderingProgram;
GLuint vao[numVAOs];
GLuint vbo[numVBOs];
GLuint vColorLoc, vPositionLoc;
//void PrintVertex(float * vertex)
//{
//  int i, n = 200;
//  cout << "数组长度为" << 2 * n << endl;
//  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
//  {
//      cout << i << '\t' << vertex[i * 2] << '\t' << vertex[i * 2 + 1] << endl;
//  }
//}

/*
导入着色器，初始化窗口
画圆需要新增参数int Precise
*/
void DrawStar(float Positionx, float Positiony, float R, float theta)//para1,para2代表五角星中心点的x,y坐标。para3表示中心点到最远顶点（五角星的尖端）处的距离。para4表示五角星的旋转角（逆时针）。且para4(theta) 属于 [0 , 2*PI)
{

    //float *Star = DrawStar(vertices, 0.2, 1);

    int x = 0, y = 1;
    int i;
    float * temp = new float[24];

    temp[0] = Positionx;
    temp[1] = Positiony;
    for (i = 2; i < 22;)
    {
        temp[i] = Positionx - (R*sin(theta + (i - 2)*CR / 2));
        temp[i + 1] = Positiony + R * cos(theta + (i - 2)*CR / 2);
        i += 4;
    }
    for (i = 4; i < 22;)
    {
        temp[i] = Positionx - (0.385*R*sin(theta + (i - 2) * CR / 2));
        temp[i + 1] = Positiony + 0.385* R * cos(theta + (i - 2) * CR / 2);
        i += 4;
    }
    temp[22] = temp[2];
    temp[23] = temp[3];
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(float), temp, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    //将VBO关联给顶点着色器中相应的顶点属性
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLoc);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 12);
    delete[]temp;
}
void DrawCircle(float Positionx, float Positiony, float R,int Pre,int inter=0)//Pre是指精度,且只能是偶数
{
    float * temp = new float[2*Pre+4];
    float *upt = new float[24];
    int i;
    temp[0] = Positionx;
    temp[1] = Positiony;
    for (i = 1; i < Pre+1; i++)
    {
        temp[2 * i] = Positionx + R * cos((i-1)*2 * PI /Pre );
        temp[2 * i + 1] = Positiony + R * sin((i - 1)*2 * PI / Pre);
    }
    temp[2 * Pre + 2] = temp[2];
    temp[2 * Pre + 3] = temp[3];
    int Inter = inter;
    float *Temp = new float[2 * Pre + 2 - 4*Inter];
    if (inter != 0)
    {
        Temp[0] = temp[0];
        Temp[1] = temp[1];
        for (i = 1 + Inter; i < 1+Pre/2; i++)
        {
            Temp[(i-Inter)*2] = temp[i*2];
            Temp[(i - Inter) * 2+1] = temp[i * 2+1];
        }
        for (i = 1+Pre / 2; i < Pre+1-Inter; i++)
        {
            Temp[(i - Inter) * 2] = temp[i * 2];
            Temp[(i - Inter) * 2 + 1] = temp[i * 2 + 1];
        }
        float theta = atan(Temp[3] / Temp[2]);
        //float k2 = (-1) / k1;
        float r1 = R / 4;
        float th = r1;

        float dx= r1 * cos(theta), dy = r1 * sin(theta);
        float xx = (temp[0] + dx) / 2, yy = (temp[0] + dy) / 2;
        xx -= th * cos(theta + PI / 2);
        yy -= th * sin(theta + PI / 2);
        upt[0] = temp[0];
        upt[1] = temp[1];
        upt[2] = xx;
        upt[3] = yy;
        upt[4] = 1 *dx;
        upt[5] = 1 * dy;
        upt[6] = 1 * dx;
        upt[7] = 1 * dy;
        upt[8] = xx+1* dx;
        upt[9] = yy+1 * dy;
        upt[10] = 2 * dx;
        upt[11] = 2 * dy;
        upt[12] = 2 * dx;
        upt[13] = 2 * dy;
        upt[14] = xx + 2 * dx;
        upt[15] = yy + 2 * dy;
        upt[16] = 3 * dx;
        upt[17] = 3 * dy;
        upt[18] = 3 * dx;
        upt[19] = 3 * dy;
        upt[20] = xx + 3 * dx;
        upt[21] = yy + 3 * dy;
        upt[22] = 4 * dx;
        upt[23] = 4 * dy;
    }
    
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    if (inter)
    {
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (2 * Pre + 2-4*Inter) * sizeof(float), Temp, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        //将VBO关联给顶点着色器中相应的顶点属性
        glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLoc);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, Pre + 1-2*Inter);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(float), upt, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        //将VBO关联给顶点着色器中相应的顶点属性
        glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLoc);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
    }
    else
    {
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (2 * Pre + 4) * sizeof(float), temp, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        //将VBO关联给顶点着色器中相应的顶点属性
        glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLoc);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, Pre + 2);
    }
    delete[]temp;
    delete[]Temp;
    delete[]upt;
}
void init(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    //编译、链接着色器程序
    renderingProgram = Utils::createShaderProgram("vertShader.glsl", "fragShader.glsl");

    glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs, vao);//生成新顶点数组，编号为numVAOs
    glGenBuffers(numVBOs, vbo);//生成缓冲区，编号为numVBOs,vbo

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer    
    //vPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(renderingProgram, "vPosition");//
    //绑定当前VAO
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    // Load the data into the GPU
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    ////将VBO关联给顶点着色器中相应的顶点属性
}
//函数绘制
void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime)
{
    renderingProgram = Utils::createShaderProgram("vertShader.glsl", "fragShader.glsl");
    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
    glClearColor(0,0,0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    vPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(renderingProgram, "vPosition");
    //绘制模型
    float StarPosition[5][2] = { {-0.12,0.15},{0.06,0.82},{0.15,0.5},{0.06,0.15},{-0.17,-0.13} };
    DrawCircle(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 200,20);

    renderingProgram = Utils::createShaderProgram("vertShader.glsl", "fragShader_test.glsl");
    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
    vPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(renderingProgram, "vPosition");
    DrawStar(StarPosition[0][0], StarPosition[0][1], 0.1, 0);
    //DrawStar(StarPosition[2][0], StarPosition[2][1], 0.15, 1.58);
    //DrawStar(StarPosition[3][0], StarPosition[3][1], 0.15, 1);
    //DrawStar(StarPosition[1][0], StarPosition[1][1], 0.15, 2.2);
    //DrawStar(StarPosition[4][0], StarPosition[4][1], 0.15, 0.65);
}

int main(void)
{
    //glfw初始化
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //窗口版本
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4); //主版本号
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); //次版本号

    //创建窗口
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "Flag", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    //设置缓存刷新时间
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)//glew初始化
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //导入着色器，创建和绑定VAO和VBO
    init(window);//若画圆，需要转到函数定义处增加所需圆的精度

    //事件循环，接收输入事件
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        display(window, glfwGetTime()); //绘制函数，主体
        glfwSwapBuffers(window); //交换颜色缓存
        glfwPollEvents(); //检查有没有触发什么事件（比如键盘输入、鼠标移动等）
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Not that I think this is the bug, but replace `float * temp = new float[24]; ` with `std::vector<float> temp(24); ` (and where you need to pointer call data() on temp). If any of the other calls throws your memory will still be deleted. In fact C++ guidelines mention to no longer use new/delete. But use std::make_unique or other containers.
https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly

Comment: Instead of e.g. `float * temp = new float[24];` why not simply `float temp[24];`? If you know the size at compile-time, and that it will be fixed and not change during run-time, use plain arrays.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Are you running the binary under any memory checking tool like sanitizer? I once ran into a similar issue. Turned out I was using sanitizer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That should take precedence over dynamic allocation (and thus my comments)

Comment: @PepijnKramer But vector container couldn't be used in glBufferData() function, I can't pass the data into the Buffer. :(

Comment: You can, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data.
You should be able to do something like this `glBuffer.data = static_cast<void*>(vector.data());`. Just be sure your vector is still in scope (same as your `new`-ed pointer to data really)

Comment: @PepijnKramer OK, I'll have a try. many thx!

Comment: First try if the array approach by Some progammer dude works. If your data is always 24 floats long then an array is better (you could use std::array<float,24> then too). You might gain a bit of performance to data will be on the stack (cache locality) instead of in global memory.

Comment: The program runs `display` for every frame, and therefore loads the shader files from disk _for every frame_. Perhaps the memory leak is there (in "Utils"). DrawCircle and DrawStar are also run for each frame, including their memory (de)allocation. Instead, you'll want to create the shader programs, VAO, VBO, etc. _once_ and upload the data _once_. And in the actual display function only bind the VAO, upload the uniforms and call glDraw*.